# How to Build a Counter Variable With code only

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a variable that can count up from 0 in milliseconds
I don't want to use the timer from the Toolbox, but build it with code.
So far I declared a timer object, but how do I bind it to an Event that can convert the time into a counter and append it to a variable?

See below what I tried so far, but without success

```
Imports System.Timers

Public Class Counter

Property Count As Integer

Private Sub Counter_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Count = Counter()
    Console.WriteLine(Count)
End Sub

Public Function Counter() As Integer
    ' Create timer
    Dim timer As Timer = New Timer()
    timer.Interval = 1000
    'AddHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf TimerEvent
    timer.AutoReset = True
    timer.Enabled = True

    Return Integer.Parse(timer.ToString())
End Function

Private Sub CountEvent(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
    'Console.WriteLine("Event Raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", e.SignalTime)
    'Console.WriteLine("Count Miliseconds {0:fff}", e.SignalTime) ' count milisecond
    Console.WriteLine("Count Seconds {0:ss}", e.SignalTime) ' count milisecond
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What is the `Counter` Class? An UserControl? A Form? What do you want to do with this class? -- `e.SignalTime` just returns `DateTime.Now`, so you'd have to store the time when the Timer is started and subtract it from the current time -- Note that the `System.Timers.Timer` event is raised in a ThreadPool Thread. So, treat UI updates carefully. You could set its `SynchronizingObject`, but that ~turns the Timer into the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` you don't want to use.

Comment: The Counter Class is just a class that I will initialize in a Form. I need to counter for the same reason you need a Timer inside a game to update the graphics on the screen.

About Subtracting the Start Time from the DateTime.Now sound like a good idea, but I can't find a way to format the time into an Integer or some other type I can use a Operator on.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my code below will help you. It will run as-is in a console app, but you just need to extract the `Counter` class.

```
Imports System.Timers
Module Module1

    Dim oCounter As Counter

    Sub Main()
        oCounter = New Counter(1000)
        AddHandler oCounter.Count, AddressOf Counter_Count
        Console.WriteLine("You can press any key to quit after 10,000 milliseconds.")
        oCounter.StartCounter()
        While oCounter.TotalMillisecondsPassed < 10000
            Console.ReadKey()
        End While
    End Sub

    Sub Counter_Count(Sender As Object, TotalMillisecondsPassed As Long)
        Console.WriteLine(TotalMillisecondsPassed & " milliseconds passed since: " & oCounter.StartTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff"))
    End Sub

' A class to keep track of the number of milliseconds passed since the 
    ' Timer was initiated and to raise an event every x number of milliseconds
    Private Class Counter

        ' The time the Counter was started
        Public ReadOnly Property StartTime As Date
            Get
                Return MyStartTime
            End Get
        End Property

        ' The total number of milliseconds that have passed
        Public ReadOnly Property TotalMillisecondsPassed As Long
            Get
                Return (Date.Now - MyStartTime).TotalMilliseconds
            End Get
        End Property

        ' The event is raised each time the interval has passed    
        Public Event Count(Sender As Object, TotalMillisecondsPassed As Long)

        Private MyStartTime As Date
        Private oTimer As Timer

        ' The interval between Count events
        Public Sub New(IntervalInMillisenconds As Integer)
            oTimer = New Timer(IntervalInMillisenconds)
            AddHandler oTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf TimerElapsed
            oTimer.AutoReset = True
        End Sub

        ' Starts the counter
        Public Sub StartCounter()
            MyStartTime = Date.Now()
            oTimer.Start()
        End Sub

        ' Stops the counter
        Public Sub StopCounter()
            oTimer.Stop()
        End Sub

        ' Handles the internal event of the timer elapsing
        Private Sub TimerElapsed(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
            RaiseEvent Count(Me, TotalMillisecondsPassed)
        End Sub

    End Class


End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

Dim Counter As Integer

```
Private Sub TimerEvent(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)

    ' Count Up
    If 1 <> 2 Then
        Counter = Counter + 1
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Count Up: " & Counter)
End Sub
```